# cannot save date in mysql datatase with php

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

I have a problem with date in php
even if I fill the textbox of the date , in the database I find it empty

here is my php page :

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (!array_key_exists("user", $_SESSION)) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
require_once("Includes/db.php");
$wisherID = WishDB::getInstance()->get_wisher_id_by_name($_SESSION['user']);

$wishDescriptionIsEmpty = false;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (array_key_exists("back", $_POST)) {
        header('Location: editWishList.php');
        exit;
    } else
    if ($_POST['wish'] == "") {
        $wishDescriptionIsEmpty = true;
    } else if ($_POST["wishID"] == "") {
        WishDB::getInstance()->insert_wish($wisherID, $_POST["wish"], $_POST["dueDate"]);
        header('Location: editWishList.php');
        exit;
    } else if ($_POST["wishID"] != "") {
        WishDB::getInstance()->update_wish($_POST["wishID"], $_POST["wish"], $_POST["dueDate"]);
        header('Location: editWishList.php');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom\development-bundle\ui\i18n\jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );

    });         
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
            $wish = array("id" => $_POST["wishID"], "description" => $_POST["wish"], "due_date" => $_POST["dueDate"]);
        else
        if (array_key_exists("wishID", $_GET))
            $wish = mysqli_fetch_array(WishDB::getInstance()->get_wish_by_wish_id($_GET["wishID"]));
        else
            $wish = array("id" => "", "description" => "", "due_date" => "");
        ?>
        <form name="editWish" action="editWish.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="wishID" value="<?php echo $wish["id"]; ?>" />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Describe your wish:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="wish"  value="<?php echo $wish['description']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><?php if ($wishDescriptionIsEmpty) echo "Please enter description"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>When do you want to get it?</td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="due_date" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo $wish['due_date']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>                
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="saveWish" value="Save Changes"/>
            <input type="submit" name="back" value="Back to the List"/>

        </form>
        je suis 
        </br>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the coresponding method in db.php :

```
function insert_wish($wisherID, $description, $dueDate) {
    $description = $this->real_escape_string($description);
    if ($duedate == '') {
        $this->query("INSERT INTO wishes (wisher_id, description)" .
                " VALUES (" . $wisherID . ", '" . $description . "')");
    } else
        $this->query("INSERT INTO wishes (wisher_id, description, due_date)" .
                " VALUES (" . $wisherID . ", '" . $description . "', '" . $dueDate . "')");
}    

public function update_wish($wishID, $description, $duedate) {
    $description = $this->real_escape_string($description);
    if ($duedate == null) {
        $this->query("UPDATE wishes SET description = '" . $description . "', due_date = NULL WHERE id = " . $wishID);
    } else
        $this->query("UPDATE wishes SET description = '" . $description . "', due_date = '" . $duedate . "' WHERE id = " . $wishID);
}
```

I use the datepicker query component for date
can you detect me the location of the error
thanks

Comment: Try to echo `$_POST["dueDate"]` whether you are getting posted date or not

Comment: Do you get any errors from MySQL? Are you sure your MySQL library is programmed to show errors? If you are using the OOP MySQLi class it will not unless you program it to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have given a wrong name to input element. Replace below

```
<input type="text" name="due_date" id="datepicker" 
       value="<?php echo $wish['due_date']; ?>" />
```

With

```
<input type="text" name="dueDate" id="datepicker" 
       value="<?php echo $wish['due_date']; ?>" />
```

You are using `$_POST["dueDate"]` to get date value and the name is incorrect in your markup.

**Edit ::**

As @simonTifo said in comment "it return me the exact date, bit in the datatabase it saves like 00-00-0000", there might be some format related issue to overcome this problem just use the **[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** function in php. So the code suppose to be :

```
WishDB::getInstance()->insert_wish($wisherID, $_POST["wish"], 
                              date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_POST["dueDate"]));
```

Check that function manual and set whatever format according to your need.

Hope this will help !!

Comment: @simonTifo, okay try to change the id as well. replace the "datepicker" id with the "dueDate"

Comment: @simonTifo did you echo $_POST["dueDate"] whats it returning?

Comment: I placed it below the form but it generated an error : `Notice: Undefined index: dueDate in C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\editWish.php on line 74`

Comment: it return me the exact date, bit in the datatabase it saves like 00-00-0000